# Does Ada really reduce bugs?

Tags: ada

I tried googling around. I found one website that talked about how many bugs were found and how much it reduce testing. But it was only one page and I found no papers that talk about it.

Is there anything published to show the time or cost savings of using Ada?

Comment: Neither [this page](http://www.adaic.org/advantages/) or [this](http://www.ddci.com/displayNews.php?fn=programs_rah66.php) appears to offer numbers. [This](http://archive.adaic.com/docs/reports/schrank/main.htm) does, but is old. [Here](http://www.adaic.org/advantages/projects/) and [here](http://www.seas.gwu.edu/~mfeldman/ada-project-summary.html) are lists of projects.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Technically I am asking for a paper or some kind of research. It isn't really asking for an opinion.

Comment: @user2814152 Even if you're right, it's probably off-topic for Stack Overflow.  It might be better for [Theoretical Computer Science](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) or another StackExchange site.

Comment: @ajb: I think [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) would be more appropriate.

Comment: would it help the situation to edit the question title, to "is there any hard evidence that Ada reduces bugs?" making it clear that opinion is NOT wanted here?

Answer (score 3):

There have been a few studies/papers, the only one that springs immediately is probably the most famous:
[Comparing Development Costs of C and Ada](http://archive.adaic.com/intro/ada-vs-c/cada_art.html) (1995)

There is also a presentation:
[Programming Languages and Lifecycle Cost](http://archive.adaic.com/docs/present/ajpo/pll-cost/html/) (1997)

Other studies:

- [A Comparison of ADA 83 and C++](http://www.sei.cmu.edu/reports/91sr004.pdf) (1991)

Also of interest [Ironsides](http://ironsides.martincarlisle.com/), which is [AFAIK] the first verified DNS-server, has a couple of papers that mention the costs of buggy/insecure software and the benefits of formal verification.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen one paper comparing the success rate of student teams in developing real time systems in either Ada or C. In that experiment, success rates were significantly higher in Ada; I'll leave the actual details to the paper.

It is "Software Engineering: On the Right Track" on [this page](http://www.cs.uni.edu/~mccormic/RealTime/)